# printing a page after checking validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want that on button click it check first validator then print command is executed
here is my ASPX Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
    }

    @media print
    {
        .header, .style1, .footer,.hide
        {
            display:none
        }
    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" style="color: #FF0000"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="window.print();" />
</asp:Content>
```

problem is that when i click on button it execute the print function and dont check validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript OnClientClick will fire before your page is validated. You could try validating the page before printing it.

```
function Validate() {
    if(Page_ClientValidate())
        window.print();
}
```

Then call it like so.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Validate();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the **CausesValidation** Property of the button to true!